# devstack install:can't run lms

Tags: devstack

I met a problem and I searched in google and read the documents in github,when I type this command:                                     returns
paver devstack lms                                                   returns
I found that it shows that:Build failed: Unknown task: devstack      returns
What's more,I found that in my /edx-platform/,there is no file,so I do not now what's wrong with it ,and Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the instructions here? https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edX-Ubuntu-12.04-64-bit-Installation if there is no files under /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform then you should clean /var/tmp and /edx and re-install the system.

Comment: Yes I have followed the instructions,and I have solved the problem by download edx-platform source code ,so it can run the lms now,and thank you very much